# Getting reference to element that invoked inline function with JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I am inserting elements into the DOM populated with some data I retrieved from a web service. I attached an inline click event to call a function when invoked. The problem is I am not getting a reference to the element that invoked that function.

Code that appends the new elements:

```
$.getJSON("/search?" + $(this).serialize(), function (data) {
  if (data != null) {
    $.each(data, function (index, video) {
      resultItem.append("<li ><a onclick='loadNewVideo(e)' href='play?video=" + video.video_id + "'>" + "<img width='185' src='" + video.defaultImg + "'/>" + "<span class='video_left_title'>" + video.song.song_name + "<h6 class='artist_name'>" + video.artist.artist_name + "</h6></span></a>");
    });
  }
});
```

Function:

```
function loadNewVideo (e) {
     e.preventDefault();
     alert($(this).attr("href"));
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of using inline event handlers, you could delegate the clicks on all `a` to `resultItem`:

```
// Call this only once, when resultItem is already in the DOM
// (for example, on a document.ready callback)
resultItem.on('click', 'a', loadNewVideo);

// Proceed with your current code (slightly modified):
function loadNewVideo (e) {
     e.preventDefault();
     alert($(this).attr("href"));
}

$.getJSON ("/search?" + $(this).serialize(),function (data) {
    if (data != null) {
        $.each (data,function (index,video) {
            resultItem.append("<li ><a href='play?video=" + video.video_id +"'>"
               + "<img width='185' src='"+video.defaultImg +"'/>"
               + "<span class='video_left_title'>"+ video.song.song_name
               + "<h6 class='artist_name'>"+video.artist.artist_name
               + "</h6></span></a>");
         });
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Inline `onclick` handlers don't go through jQuery, which is why you don't have access.

You can either leave those there and change the handler:

```
function loadNewVideo(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  alert($(e.target).attr("href"));
}
```

Or, and more preferably, don't use the inline handlers. Just give the `a` elements a class of `video` (or whatever) and install handlers with jQuery:

```
...
resultItem.append("<li><a class='video' href=...'")
...

// and elsewhere
$(resultItem).on('click', 'a.video', loadNewVideo);
```

Comment: good point, those elements won't be in the DOM yet. Editing my answer to attach the handler to the resultItem list.

Answer (score 0):

jQuery's event object allowed me to grab what the documentation calls the '[current DOM element within the event bubbling phase](http://api.jquery.com/event.currentTarget/)'.

```
var originatingElement = event.currentTarget;
```